# Is it possible to use .mylogin.cnf file in c# to establish connection?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I am a newbie when it comes to C# connector and MySQL, so please bear with me.

If C/C++ application uses .mylogin.cnf file to connect to MySQL server, can we use the same file in C#, and how?

I did search if it is possible to use the same file to connect to server when using C#, but could not find the way.

I would really appreciate if somebody could let me know if this is possible and how (short example or a link to a site with an example would be great). If it is not possible then what would be the best way to accomplish functionally similar way of connecting? Custom plugin? We use Community Server.

Thanks.

Comment: What is inside this `cnf` file?

Comment: cnf file contains encrypted information MySQL connector needs in order to connect. In C you would use mysql_real_connect() function, after you specify in mysql_options() MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_GROUP, and using MySQL configuration editor you enter data for mysql connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to use `.mylogin.cnf` from the .NET Connector library. In .NET, the connection options are always specified in a "connection string" passed to `MySqlConnection`.

If the settings in `.mylogin.cnf` were created with:

```
mysql_config_editor set --host=HostName --port=1234 \
  --user=UserName --password=Passw0rd
```

then the equivalent C# code is:

```
new MySqlConnection("Server=HostName;Port=1234;UserID=UserName;Password=Passw0rd")
```

or:

```
var csb = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    Server = "HostName",
    Port = 1234u,
    UserID = "UserName",
    Password = "Passw0rd",
};
var connection = new MySqlConnection(csb.ConnectionString);
```